# Creating dynamic dropdown options based off dropdown selection - stuck

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-templates

So I am trying to create a dynamic form where the 2nd dropdown box is populated based on the first dropdown.

I am using `ajax` & `jquery` to help build this dynamic form in my django project, and I need a bit of help.  I have got the ajax call to work properly, and I have sent my choices back to the form, but now I am having trouble populating the form with my choices.

Can someone help me make the json output turn into html options?

Here is my ajax.py:

```
def switch_plan(request, *args, **kwargs):
    from plans.models import Plan, OwnershipType, MemberType, PlanMember
    from datetime import datetime
    now = datetime.now()
    json = {}
    data = request.POST
    plan_type = data.get('plan-plan_type')
    print plan_type

    if request.is_ajax():
        if plan_type == '5':
            ownership = OwnershipType.objects.all().exclude(id=3).exclude(id=8).exclude(id=9)
            json['owner_types'] = ownership

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(json), mimetype='application/json')
```

My plans.html js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#id_plan-plan_type").change(function() {
        q = $("form").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url plans-switch_plan %}",
            dataType: "json",
            data: q,
            success: function(json) {
                //need help here
            }
        });
    });
});
```

`$("#id_plan-ownership_type")` is the select field that I need to add the options to.

**Edit** My json output is as follows `{'owner_types': [<OwnershipType: Corporate/Non-Corporate>, <OwnershipType: Estate>, <OwnershipType: In Trust For>, <OwnershipType: Joint Subscriber>, <OwnershipType: Single Subscriber>, <OwnershipType: Tenants in Common>]}`

Comment: An aside: it's probably best not to use hard-coded `id`s for your `OwnershipType` or `plan_type` objects in the view. In addition to being completely inscrutable to read, it depends on the DB being in exactly the right format. If you just have an index on some kind of slug-type field, you won't take any significant speed penalty by using that instead, and it'll make maintaining this code significantly easier.

Comment: Have you tried [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your success callback:

```
$.each(json.owner_types, function(i, value){
    var opt = $("<option></option>");
    opt.text(value.name);
    opt.val(value.id);
    $("#id_plan-ownership_type").append(opt);
})
```

You also need to extract your model data into a JSON-serializable type like a dictionary, something along the lines of:

```
json["owner_types"] = [{"name": o.name, "id": o.id}
        for o in OwnershipType.objects.all()] # or .filter(...)
```

Comment: it doesn't appear to be doing anything.. almost like its not successful?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not your JSON output, that looks like a python `repr()`. Can you see what the AJAX response body is using firebug? Typically you can't just serialize django models with `dumps()`, you need to extract the relevant data into something simplejson can deal with (eg, a dictionary).

Comment: `TypeError
[<OwnershipType: Corporate/Non-Corporate>, <OwnershipType: Estate>, <OwnershipType: In Trust For>, <OwnershipType: Joint Subscriber>, <OwnershipType: Single Subscriber>, <OwnershipType: Tenants in Common>] is not JSON serializable` is what it is showing

Comment: See updated answer, django models aren't directly JSON serializable.