# How do I get a cascading drop down selection box with my foreign keys in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

So I have a model called `Car` with a foreign key of a `Manufacturer` model. I also have a `CarCharacterisitcs` model with a foreign key of `Car`.

This is what the code looks like:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    idcar = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=765)

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    idmanufacturer = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=765)

class CarCharacteristics(models.Model):
    idcar_characteristics = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I am making a page that lets you add `CarCharacteristics`.

This is my form and view:

```
class CarCharacteristicsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CarCharacterisitics

def add_car_characteristics(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        car_char_form = CarCharacterisiticsForm(request.POST)
        if car_char.is_valid(:
            car_char_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/cars/car-characterisitcs')
    else:
        car_char_form = CarCharacterisiticsForm()
    return render(request, 'car_characteristics/add_car_characteristics.html',{'car_char_form': car_char_form,})
```

In my html page, I have this:

```
<h1>Car Characteristics</h1>
<form action="." method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <table id="characteristics_table">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <table id="car_characterisitcs_table">
            <td>{{ char_char_form.as_table }}</td>
        </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

When this form is displayed, I have a drop down select field with all my possible `Car` models. What I want is to have two select fields. I want the first to let you be able to select the `Manufacturer` and then the second to display all the possible `Cars` that have that manufacturer. Then when you submit the form, it assigns the `Car` you selected to the Foreign Key of the `CarCharacterisitcs` model.

If you go look at [Advance Auto Parts](http://shop.advanceautoparts.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/home___), when you click "Your Vehicle", that is what I want to have. How do I do that?

Comment: Couple of previous answers that might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214618/creating-dynamic-dropdown-options-based-off-dropdown-selection-stuck  and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914358/django-chain-select  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233850/django-jquery-cascading-select-boxes

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX to fetch the data for a selected manufacturer and populate the car field accordingly. This needs to be done inside the view code and return the car fetched data in to the template and use the template language to populate the field.